# A Django form is automatically being populated with another user's email address

Tags: django, session, django-users

This one is blowing my mind and freaking me out to about the same degree.

I have a signup page here: http://eatfeastly.com (I restarted the server on midnight, Aug 15, which temporarily fixes the problem, so you may need to wait to see the issue)

You'll notice that it has some user's email already prepopulated. Note that means that this data is not just in my cache. It goes without saying this is *BAD* for our users.

I use the following MVT for this:

### Model

```
class PotentialUser(CommonInfo):
    is_cook = models.BooleanField()
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True, validators=[validate_no_existing_user_email])
    location = models.CharField(max_length=500, help_text="Please enter city, state.")
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

    class LOCATION:
        DC = "Washington, DC"
        NY = "New York City, NY"
        SF = "San Francisco, CA"
        OTHER = "Other"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def send_signup_email(self):
        # Can't use django notifications here, since it requires an actual user, and this is only a potential user
        msg = MultipartTemplateEmailMessage('signup_complete',
            from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
            to=[self.email],
            part_templates=(
                ('full.txt', 'text/plain'),
            ),
            context={
                'recipient': self,
                'support_email': settings.SUPPORT_EMAIL,
                # shortened from:
                # http://eatfeastly.com/?utm_source=cont-e-pot&utm_medium=email-auto&utm_content=feedme&utm_campaign=e-share
                'share_url': "http://goo.gl/X2VtA",
            },
        )
        msg.send()
```

### Form

```
class PotentialUserModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Override to make this field required
    is_cook = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        required=True,
        coerce=bool,
        choices=(
            ('cook', True),
            ('feaster', False),
            ('both', True),
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = PotentialUser

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(PotentialUserModelForm, self).clean()
        location = cleaned_data.get('location')
        if location == "Other":
            zipcode = cleaned_data.get('zipcode')
            if zipcode is None or zipcode == '':
                if not 'zipcode' in self._errors:
                    self._errors['zipcode'] = ErrorList()
                self._errors['zipcode'].append("Zipcode is required")
                del cleaned_data['zipcode']
        return cleaned_data
```

### View

```
class PotentialUserCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = PotentialUserModelForm
    template_name = "intro/home.html"
    form_focused = False

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('potential_user_thanks', self.object.pk)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['LOCATION'] = PotentialUser.LOCATION
        if self.form_focused or hasattr(kwargs['form'], 'errors') and kwargs['form'].errors:
            kwargs['form_focused'] = True
        else:
            kwargs['form_focused'] = False
        return super(PotentialUserCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Save the user to the database and set self.object
        response = super(PotentialUserCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
        self.object.send_signup_email()
        return response
```

### Template

```
<!-- ... -->
<form id="intro_form" action="{% url signup %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div id="intro_form_box" class="vcenter_outer">
        <div class="field_container">
            {{ form.email.errors }}
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="yourname@domain.com"
                    value="{{ form.email.value|default_if_none:'' }}"/>
        </div>

        <div class="field_container">
            {{ form.is_cook.errors }}
            <span>I'm a</span>
            <input type="radio" id="cook_button" class="form_button" name="is_cook"
                {% if form.is_cook.value == 'cook' %}checked="checked"{% endif %} value="cook"/>
            <label for="cook_button">Cook</label>
            <input type="radio" id="feaster_button" class="form_button" name="is_cook"
                {% if form.is_cook.value == 'feaster' %}checked="checked"{% endif %} value="feaster"/>
            <label for="feaster_button">Feaster</label>
            <input type="radio" id="both_button" class="form_button" name="is_cook"
                {% if form.is_cook.value == 'both' %}checked="checked"{% endif %} value="both"/>
            <label for="both_button">Both</label>
        </div>

        <div class="field_container">
            {{ form.location.errors }}
            <span>from</span>
            {# These location values should match the Area values in the database #}
            <input type="radio" id="dc_button" class="form_button" name="location"
                {% if form.location.value == LOCATION.DC %}checked="checked"{% endif %} value="{{ LOCATION.DC }}"/>
            <label for="dc_button">{{ LOCATION.DC }}</label>
            <input type="radio" id="ny_button" class="form_button" name="location"
                {% if form.location.value == LOCATION.NY %}checked="checked"{% endif %} value="{{ LOCATION.NY }}"/>
            <label for="ny_button">{{ LOCATION.NY }}</label>
            <input type="radio" id="sf_button" class="form_button" name="location"
               {% if form.location.value == LOCATION.SF %}checked="checked"{% endif %} value="{{ LOCATION.SF }}"/>
            <label for="sf_button">{{ LOCATION.SF }}</label>
            <input type="radio" id="other_button" class="form_button" name="location"
               {% if form.location.value == LOCATION.OTHER %}checked="checked"{% endif %} value="{{ LOCATION.OTHER }}"/>
            <label for="other_button">Other</label>
            <div id="zipcode_container"
                {# only show the container if other is checked or there are validation errors #}
                {% if form.zipcode.errors %}
                    class="field_error"
                {% else %}{% if form.location.value != LOCATION.OTHER %}
                    style="display:none;"
                {% endif %}{% endif %}
                    >
                <div>
                    <span>
                        Sorry Feastly only works in select cities at the moment.<br/>
                        <b>Enter your zip code</b> and we'll let you know when you can join!
                    </span>
                    <label>
                        {{ form.zipcode.errors }}
                        <input type="text" id="other_location" name="zipcode" maxlength="5"
                               value="{{ form.zipcode.value|default_if_none:'' }}"
                               placeholder="zip code"/>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="feed_me" type="submit">Feed me!</button>
</form>
<!-- ... -->
```

Here is another weird piece to the puzzle: some user's emails do not have an associated PotentialUser model in the database, but instead have a Django User model.

Now here's the kicker: it does not happen on my development machine, nor on our staging environment. Both of these environments have their own override settings, but those don't seem to have any affect. I have only been testing this by myself.

What does seem to fix it however, is restarting the server. Until something happens, either a another user logs in on another computer or something (!?), and a user's email begins to show up on the signup page.

What could be causing this? Could this be a user's session leaking into other connections? If so, how does that work / happen? And most importantly, how should I approach fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: How long should I wait to see it?

Comment: I don't see it either, 9 hours later. I'm thinking your browser(s) are automatically filling it.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know what caused/s it. This may only happen after some rare event. Restarting the server seemed to fix it for now. I'll update if it shows up again.

Comment: Okay, it's happening again (http://eatfeastly.com)

Comment: You're just gonna have to trust me on this, because I need to restart the server again. I don't feel confortable leaving these emails floating on the site.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I know it is not my browser because people who have never been to the site are reporting they see the exact same email as I see.

Comment: @JeffMay Did you ever solve this? I have a similar issue and can't find anything on this... =(

Comment: I never solved it, but it stopped being a problem (for now).

Comment: Do you use caching on the production site?

Comment: I had similar problem maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068382/first-name-last-name-and-email-address-leak-in-forms-randomly Did you solve it?